# Flexbox not wrapping after 12 column items

Tags: html, sass, flexbox

I can't seem to get the flexbox `.col` to wrap after 12 items.

Here is my flexbox scss:

```
.container{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 1170px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.col{
    max-width: 8.333333%;
    flex-basis: 8.33333333%;
    flex: 1 auto;
    margin: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

Here is a fiddle that will help show the sample better:
https://jsfiddle.net/2Lrwcvpg/

Comment: change max-width to width ...it should work

Answer (score 0):

Use "max-width" For Container and now it work.

.container{

```
display: flex;    
flex-wrap: wrap;     
max-width: 1170px;   
margin-right: auto;   
margin-left: auto;   
box-sizing: content-box;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If it should wrap after 12 items

Make these changes. check the following snippet

```css
.container{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.col{
    max-width: 6.2%;
    flex-basis: 8.33%;
    flex: 1 auto;
    margin: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<style media="screen">
    .col, .col-2{
        background-color: orange;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col">
        test
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        test
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        test
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        test
    </div><div class="col">
        test
    </div><div class="col">
        test
    </div><div class="col">
        test
    </div><div class="col">
        test
    </div><div class="col">
        test
    </div><div class="col">
        test
    </div><div class="col">
        test
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        test
    </div>


    <div class="col">
        test
    </div><div class="col">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps